# how to get type T with shared_ptr<T>?

Tags: c++, c++17, priority-queue, type-traits

I have a struct:

```
class Priority
{
public:
    int priority;

    bool operator>(const Priority& other) const
    {
        if (priority > other.priority) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I implement this:

```
using T = Priority;
std::priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>> pq;
```

It works and calls `operator>` in `Priority` when sorting by `priority`.

But, when I change it to this:

```
using T = shared_ptr<Priority>;
std::priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>> pq;
```

Then it reports an error when compiling.

So, is there any way to make it OK without changing `class Priority` and using its own `operator>`, but not using some additional function or lambda in comparing `shared_prt<Priority>`?

I think maybe it could be done by changing `greater<T>` into `greater<type traits from T into Priority>`? But how?

---

Thanks for answers.
By the way, is it OK to use a proxy class like

```
class Sptr_Priority
{
public:
    shared_ptr<Priority> p;

    Sptr_Priority()
    {
        p = make_shared<Priority>();
    };

    Sptr_Priority(int i)
    {
        p = make_shared<Priority>(i);
    };

    bool operator>(const Sptr_Priority& other) const
    {
        if (*p > *(other.p)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    shared_ptr<Priority> operator->()
    {
        return p;
    }
};
```

And I call it by

```
using T = Sptr_Priority;
std::priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>> pq;
```

Comment: Narrowly, the answer is yes: `std::shared_ptr` defines a [member type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr#Member_types) `element_type` whose type, in this case, would be `Priority`. However, `greater<Priority>` still won't help you compare elements of type `shared_ptr<Priority>`. I don't think there's a built-in "dereference and compare" functor.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` needs a comparator that compares `T`s, not some perhaps tangentially related other type.  If you want to compare `std::shared_ptr<Priority>`s by comparing the `Priority`s they point to then you need a comparator that does that.  `std::greater` doesn't do that.

Comment: @NathanPierson Oh~ appreciate that, but how to get Priority from shared_ptr<Priority> with type traits?

Comment: Your thinking about this wrong. You don't need to get the type `T` you are defining that. You need to define a comparison type.

Comment: Given that `shared_ptr` isn't comparable using a specialisation/instantiation of `std::greater()`, the answer is "no".    The solution is exactly what you have said you don't want - using some additional function or lambda that does the comparison.   For example `std::priority_queue<T, vector<T>, [](const T &a, const T& b) {return std::greater(*a, *b);})` or  using some additional function or lambda that does the comparison.   Alternatively, you need to provide a `operator>()` that compares instances of `std::shared_ptr<Priority>` rather than comparing instances of `Priority`

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking bout this wrong:

```
using T = shared_ptr<Priority>;
std::priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>> pq;
```

Here you are defining a priority queue that uses `greater<shared_ptr<Priority>>` to compare the values (and thus sort them). This `std::greater` functor uses `bool operator>()` (greater than comparetor) but the type `shared_ptr<Priority>` does not have a greater than comparator defined.

You need to define a type that can be used to compare objects in the vector of type `shared_ptr<Priority>`.

```
using T = shared_ptr<Priority>;
auto comp = [](T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {return (*lhs) > (*rhs);};
using Comp = decltype(comp);
std::priority_queue<T, vector<T>, Comp>> pq(comp);
```

Comment: Is it OK to use a proxy class like I added just now?

Comment: @f1msch Sure. You can simplify that comparison: `bool operator>(const Sptr_Priority& other) const {return *p > other->p;}`